# Database row len() can be print, but this value can’t be shown in tkinter entry

Tags: sqlite, tkinter, python-3.8

I can”t understood, why I can print the value of rows, but not populate this to a tkinter entry.

My code:

```
cursor.execute(‘SELECT * FROM contacts;’)
print(‘row in table contacts:’,len(cursor.fetchall())) # prints 104
self.no_count.set(len(cursor.fetchall())) # populate 0
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the fetched data inside a variable and then access it through the variable. This is because a cursor is like a python generator, and once you use `cursor.fetchall()` the results will no longer contain the result again. So go for something like:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts;')
data = cursor.fetchall() # Store in variable
print(f'row in table contacts: {len(data)}') # Used f strings instead of comma(can be ignored)
self.no_count.set(len(data))
```

Or you could also go for the inefficient way of repeating your query each time, like:

```
cursor.execute(‘SELECT * FROM contacts;’)
print(f‘row in table contacts: {len(cursor.fetchall())}')
cursor.execute(‘SELECT * FROM contacts;’) # Repeat the query
self.no_count.set(len(cursor.fetchall())) # Fetch again
```